# VMware vCPU is the core of physical socket or logical threading?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

As the title, My physical esxi has 2 sockets with 10 cores on each. 40 logical cores in total. I have this vm assigned 20 vCPUs, my question is that this 20 vCPUs assigned to this vm are 20 cores or 20 hyper threadings?

Comment: The better question is why you need 20 vCPUs in your virtual machine. Are you sure it's necessary?

Comment: Video software requires that much.

Comment: Don't use all available physical cores for a single VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMware ESXi will present [individual threads as independent vCPUs](http://vmwarebits.com/content/vcpu-and-logical-cpu-sizing-hyper-threading-explained), so a dual socket 10-core per-socket HT-enabled system will be able to use 40 vCPUs.  So your 20 vCPU instance will use 20 threads.  However, VMware [caution against using hyperthreading](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.resmgmt.doc/GUID-3362A2E9-AB03-4C10-B9A1-3E6CA78D399B.html) in high-CPU consumption scenarios.